# Exclude referral traffic in Google Analyics

Tags: google-analytics

I have tried several ways to exclude a specific website from my referral traffic, but nothing has worked. I even talked to google analytics on the phone, and the issue is still not resolved. I would love any suggestions on excluding a specific site from my traffic!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What solution did you end up with?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom filter to exclude this referral source by "Campaign Source". Also creating a hostname inclusion filter can help if you are having referral spam.